# IllegalStateException when Setting ImageView Click Method

Tags: android, imageview, click, android-view

I am trying to allow for an ImageView click to start an intent and open a new activity. I had read about some issues doing it programmatically (I am using butterknife), so I figured I would try and set the onClick through XML:

```
private void toComments(View rootView) {
    switch (rootView.getId()) {
        case R.id.comments_label_icon:
            Intent toComments = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Discussion_Activity.class);
            toComments.putExtra("POLL_ID", pollID);
            startActivity(toComments);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
        <ImageView
            android:onClick="toComments"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/comments_label_icon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/android_chat"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            />
```

I am receiving this error:

```
03-01 20:28:46.105 15074-15074/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 15074
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method toComments(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'comments_label_icon'
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19311)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make toComments public instead:

```
public void toComments(View rootView)
```

Also it should live in the Activity that's displaying the view.

Comment: still producing the same error...I had read on a different post it had something to do with the fact that the ImageView was in a FrameLayout..

Comment: Well, I can tell you the doc makes it clear that the method must be public.  Not sure what the problem could be now.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Comment: Got it, appreciate your help

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I created the toComments() method within a Fragment as opposed to an activity

Comment: Yeah, put it in the Activity hosting the view.  The doc also mentions that this method should be attached a Context.  An Activity is a context, a fragment is not.  Updated answer too.

Comment: To be honest, I have never been a fan of the onClick property.  I usually prefer to just find the view and setOnClickListener directly on it, but this is all a matter of preference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105067/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-doug-stevenson).